# Getting orange highlight color in the padding space of gridView on click

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting a orange highlight color in the GridView, when i press it. As I have specified the padding, this highlight appears in that area.

Can somebody please help me to know, how to avoid it?

I have used OnKeyDown event for the GridView, but call does not comes to that. As such the adapter provides images for the region which is left without the padding.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to add a non-link answer:

In the `xml` for the `gridView`, add the following attribute

```
android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

That will make the selected state color of the `gridView` transparent, and will, in effect remove the orange highlighting.